# Unity Video Player, the video cannot be played properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-player

I am developing a game for android and ios via Unity. I have to play a video in a scene in the game and I use the video player component for this. I get the video link on local using xampp. And the video I'm trying to play is in mp4 format. But when I start the game, the video cannot be played properly. I am not getting an error, but video looks like the picture I send. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can you help me? I also share the code I used and related pictures with you.

```
public VideoPlayer videoplayer;
public string videoUrl="urlgir";
void Start() {
videoplayer.url = videoUrl;
videoplayer.audioOutputMode=VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
videoplayer.EnableAudioTrack (0, true);
    videoplayer.Prepare (); }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just in general why do you set the URL in start **and** via the Inspector? And have you tried to remove the `PlayOnAwake`? Is your color format correct?

Comment: If I load the video into the unity and set the video player as video clip instead of url, the video plays properly. But when I try to get the same video from local as url, it doesn't work. For this reason, I think the color format is correct, the problem is in the url part. So I did it to see if setting the url through the inspector at startup would fix the problem. And also when I uninstall PlayOnAwake the result is the same.